jclouds 2.5.0 unrecognized os family
i am facing the following behavior using a jclouds 2.5.0. My retrieved AWS Image has an "unrecognized" os family (with a os system version set to 0.0). In debug i understand how it is set but not why...
At this level (screenshot below), family is set to "ubuntu" because of the image location "590184125972/ubuntu2204-cloud-with-RSA" (including the image name "ubuntu2204-cloud-with-RSA")

Then at the reviseParsedImage level, it tries to deduce the os family by considering existing pattern in the image location (based on "amzn" and "amazon" strings) but it fails and falls into the else condition by sadly setting the os family to "unrecognized"

Any idea ?
Thx a lot
Michael
